# Can any version of Apollo server / express be used with latest version of Apollo client 3, 4 or latest

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, react-apollo, apollo-server

We have a project which uses the Apollo client on frontend and Apollo express server on the BE. With following versions,

BE Apollo server:

```
"apollo-engine": "^1.1.1",
"apollo-server-express": "^1.3.6",
```

FE Apollo client:

```
"apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.2.10",
"react-apollo": "^2.1.6",
"apollo-client": "^2.4.2",
"apollo-link-context": "^1.0.3",
"apollo-link-error": "^1.0.3",
"apollo-link-http": "^1.5.3",
"apollo-utilities": "^1.3.2",
```

And have very noob question. Can we upgrade the client on frontend to version 3 or 4, to use hooks and other new optimize functionality without upgrading the BE server. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to the documentation of Apollo Client

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/

Where you can read

> Apollo Client is a comprehensive state management library for
> JavaScript that enables you to manage both local and remote data with
> GraphQL. Use it to fetch, cache, and modify application data, all
> while automatically updating your UI.

We can say that there is no direct binding from Apollo Clinet and Apollo Server, since the client is used to work with GraphQl, independently from how the server is implemented internally. You can use Apollo Client with non Apollo Servers too.